# understanding working of Drools guvnor

Tags: drools, rule-engine, inference

can any one plz let me know that how drool guvnor work i went to guvnor documentation but couldn't understand the core logic of how rules are processed and how we can use drools guvnor in coherence with java code

Basically i want to know how java code interacts with drools guvnor api.

Answer (score 0):

There is very less documentation about latest drool 6. 
I suggest you watch [this presentation by Mark Proctor](http://www.slideshare.net/MarkProctor/drools-60-red-hat-summit-34589970) on drools 6 (Drools Project Lead at Red Hat) and visit his [Youtube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/ukmdproctor/videos) to watch screencasts of [drools workbench](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vj3MNmiUnvY&index=2&list=PLb9jQNHBKBRj9IJkc_F5nCJAvXaegOGW8) and tutorials on building example applications.