# Understanding drools-guvnor

Tags: java, drools, business-rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java code to access drool guvnor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976677/java-code-to-access-drool-guvnor)

Can any one please help by providing an example in which rules (mentioned in .drl file) are called in java code and processed(using Drools-Guvnor) ?

My previous attempt to understand the drools is [understanding working of Drools guvnor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636706/understanding-working-of-drools-guvnor), where i understood basic functioning of it but i want to learn complete working of it with an example of how we can incorporate drools-guvnor in java program

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet - can you please help on this