# java code to access drools guvnor

Tags: java, drools

We have a project requirement to access the guvnor through a web application .Can any one let me know how to access guvnor through java code ?

Answer (score 5):

The mortgage-example already has some example code. And the Drools Expert manual probably explains it in detail.
Here's the code:

```
private static KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase() throws Exception {
    KnowledgeAgent kagent = KnowledgeAgentFactory
            .newKnowledgeAgent( "MortgageAgent" );
    kagent.applyChangeSet( ResourceFactory
            .newClassPathResource( "changeset.xml" ) );
    KnowledgeBase kbase = kagent.getKnowledgeBase();
    kagent.dispose();
    return kbase;
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<change-set xmlns='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set'
    xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xs:schemaLocation='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set drools-change-set-5.0.xsd'>
  <add>
    <resource
  source='http://localhost:8080/guvnor-webapp/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/mortgages/LATEST'
  type='PKG' basicAuthentication='enabled' username='admin' password='admin' />

  </add>
</change-set>
```

Answer (score 0):

We should document that in the Guvnor reference manual. Here's [the issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/GUVNOR-1397).