# Null Pointer Exception with  Drools-Guvnor 

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, inference

I’m using the example code from the Red Hat Magazine - http://magazine.redhat.com/2008/08/12/jboss-drools-how-to-tuning-guvnor-part-1/ - to try to get the sample code to work, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)

        at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)

        at org.drools.agent.RuleAgent.loadFromProperties(RuleAgent.java:299)

        at org.drools.agent.RuleAgent.newRuleAgent(RuleAgent.java:256)

        at test.GuvnorTest.main(GuvnorTest.java:15)
```

I don't know where is guvnor.properties file .How to create how to get this file .

My previous attempt to learn drools-guvnor are following
  1)[understanding working of Drools guvnor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636706/understanding-working-of-drools-guvnor)
  2)[Understanding drools-guvnor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777185/understanding-drools-guvnor)

Comment: What code is causing this acception?  Step through your code until it explodes please.

Answer (score 0):

Nullpointers are the easiest of easiest exceptions to catch in a Java program. From your stack trace, it is clear that it is not able to read the line from one of the property files. If you debug, you could notice which path it is trying to access to and perhaps that would be the place you should be placing your guvnor property file as well.

Comment: HI I removed this error ..actually my code was not able to locate the Guvnor.properties file .. and i found that it should be placed under src/main/java so that when class will be loaded its binaries will be created and then it will be available to my code.... Thanks :)

Comment: The same code is now throwing 401 server-Exception ...please help at http://serverfault.com/questions/263375/401-exception-in-java-code